# Deploying database driven application using wamp server

Tags: java, mysql, database, deployment, wampserver

I am working on a database driven application in netbeans 8.1, and I am using wampserver for mysql. I would like to know how I could deploy(.exe) this application to a window XP machine. I have checked quite a few tutorials but all of them show me how to do it with a non database application.

Please let me know any tutorials or anything of that sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install a MySQL server on the XP, which is compatible with the given OS. From [here](http://www.mysql.com/support/supportedplatforms/database.html) you can see that version 5.5 is compatible with Windows XP. You need to connect to the given database server using your application. So, the ingredients:

- install MySQL Server 5.5 on your Windows XP
- export the database from your MySQL you are using with WAMP
- import the database to the newly installed MySQL Server 5.5 on your Windows XP
- make sure that your application connects to the MySQL server

Potential problem: You might experience problems if you used a newer version of MySQL server in your wamp. These are version-problems and you need to make your database and the application backwards compatible with MySQL Server 5.5.

Or, on the other hand: you might decide to use a newer operating system.

Comment: thank you for the anwser. After that i just need to convert the jar to exe or to an installer and then will i be done?

Comment: you can execute jar files under xp as well. Just install Java

Comment: Can you please tell me how I can embed my mysql database to the jar file.? ;The problem is that I did follow the steps in this tutorial <https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/java-db.html?print=yes> but then when i run the  sql script it is generating error with regard to the syntax. Am I in the right track or am i just going in the wrong direction. Please let me know, Is there an easier way to deploy my database with jar file.

Comment: You do not have to deploy the database to the jar file. You need to install the MySQL server and import the database there. If you can run things from its command-line, then you are on the right path. The jar file needs to connect to the right database server with the right connection (url, username, password). So, you need MySQL server installed on your computer hosting the database and you need to connect to that with the jar.